# Is there any tool which allow to manage the space between two different shapes in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: drawing number 7]

AS a beginner sometimes, face problem while making some shapes which has same space between them. As mentioned in the following example, how to deal with such issues?

Comment: Dont draw the shape draw only the center of the shape and make a thick stroke. Or use offset and delete other half.

Comment: @joojaa, what do you mean by drawing the center of the shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw 1 side, copy, join

[image]

---

Or draw 1 path, set a thick stroke, Expand, then adjust the ends if necessary.

[image]

---

You could also draw a rectangle and use Envelope Distort to bend it. Although this may be the least efficient manner.

---

As for a tool to deal with spacing and gaps between objects, although I don't *really* think that's the heart of the question. You could look at [CollierScirbe](https://astutegraphics.com/plugins/colliderscribe).